# Searching a record for two customer search terms

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, class

I have code (mostly coding I found online and tweaked a bit) that puts two search boxes on a Visualforce page and pulls search results independently of one another. 
[image: search results]

What I'm trying to do is use a Visualforce page to take those two search terms and only present records that contain both items. The reason I have to do it this way is because our sales team does not have access to create or edit list views. Would this be possible?

```
<apex:page standardController="lead" extensions="leadsearchcontroller">  
<apex:form >  
<apex:inputText value="{!searchstring}" label="Input"/> 
<apex:commandButton value="Search records" action="{!search}"/> 
<apex:pageBlock title="Search Result">  
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!lead}" var="a">  
 <apex:column>  
  <apex:outputlink value="https://ap1.salesforce.com/{!a.id}">{!a.Name}  
  </apex:outputlink>        
 </apex:column>  
 <apex:column value="{!a.route_preferences__c}"/>  
 <apex:column value="{!a.from_location__c}"/>
 <apex:column value="{!a.to_location__c}"/>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>  
 </apex:pageblock>      
    <apex:inputText value="{!searchstring2}" label="Input"/> 
      <apex:commandButton value="Search records" action="{!search2}"/> 
<apex:pageBlock title="Search Result">  
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!lead2}" var="b">  
<apex:column>  
<apex:outputlink value="https://ap1.salesforce.com/{!b.id}">{!b.Name}              
</apex:outputlink>
</apex:column>  
<apex:column value="{!b.route_preferences__c}"/>  
<apex:column value="{!b.from_location__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!b.to_location__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>  
</apex:pageblock>    
</apex:form>
</apex:page>



public with sharing class leadsearchcontroller{  
public leadsearchcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {  
}  
public list <lead> lead {get;set;} 
public string searchstring {get;set;}  
public void search(){
 string searchquery='select Route_Preferences__c, name, from_location__c,
 to_location__c, from lead where
 Route_Preferences__c like \'%'+searchstring+'%\' or from_location__c like
 \'%'+searchstring+'%\' or to_location__c like \'%'+searchstring+'%\' or
  like \'%'+searchstring+'%\' Limit 200';  
 lead= Database.query(searchquery); 
 }   
 public list <lead> lead2 {get;set;} 
 public string searchstring2 {get;set;} 
 public void search2(){
 string searchquery2='select Route_Preferences__c, name, from_location__c,
 to_location__c, from lead where
 Route_Preferences__c like \'%'+searchstring2+'%\' or from_location__c like
 \'%'+searchstring2+'%\' or to_location__c like \'%'+searchstring2+'%\' or
  like \'%'+searchstring2+'%\' Limit 200';  
 lead2= Database.query(searchquery2);
 }
 public void clear(){  
 lead.clear();  
 }  
 }
```

Comment: Not clear on what you're asking. Are you wanting to modify your two queries to only return results that contain both search terms in the fields you're selecting on?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply! That's exactly it. Only records I want displayed in the results box are records that contain both search queries. Ideally, the Visualforce page would only contain the two search boxes, one Search Records button, and one area for results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your clarifying comments, if you want to combine the text from both fields into a single search and get a single result set you can change your search() function to something like this:

```
public void search(){
      String cleanSearch1 = '%' + searchstring + '%';
      String cleanSearch2 = '%' + searchstring2 + '%';

      leads = [SELECT Route_Preferences__c, name, from_location__c,to_location__c 
       FROM  Lead
       WHERE Route_Preferences__c LIKE :cleanSearch1 OR Route_Preferences__c LIKE :cleanSearch2 
       OR from_location__c LIKE :cleanSearch1 OR from_location__c LIKE :cleanSearch2
       OR to_location__c LIKE :cleanSearch1 OR to_location__c LIKE cleanSearch2 LIMIT 200];
}
```

The `cleanSearch1` and `cleanSearch2` variables just add % to the beginning and end of your search terms so you don't have to keep doing that in the query.

I also changed from a string based query to the [] syntax. You don't seem to need dynamic SOQL here so it's a bit cleaner. It also uses bind variables (the : before cleansearch1 and cleansearch2 in the query). This is safer than just putting user input directly into the query. [This article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_SQL_Injection) is a pretty good read on security and SOQL. There's also a [security Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/secdev_injection_vulnerabilities/units/secdev_inject_get_started_wappsec) if you're interested.

The final query combines your two queries using OR statements. It will return any lead with something like search term 1 OR search term 2 in ANY of the fields you're selecting on up to 200 leads.

It's setting the results to your `leads` variable so the results will all show up in your first list.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, John. This is the coding I ended up with but definitely could not have figured it out without your help.

```
public with sharing class leadsearchcontroller{  
public leadsearchcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {  
}  
public list <lead> lead {get;set;} 
public string searchstring {get;set;}  
public string searchstring2 {get;set;}
public void search(){
  String cleanSearch1 = '%' + searchstring + '%';
  String cleanSearch2 = '%' + searchstring2 + '%';

  lead = [SELECT Route_Preferences__c, name, from_location__c,to_location__c  
  FROM  Lead
  WHERE 
  (Route_Preferences__c LIKE :cleanSearch1 OR from_location__c LIKE 
  :cleanSearch1 OR to_location__c LIKE :cleanSearch1)
  AND 
  (Route_Preferences__c LIKE :cleanSearch2 OR from_location__c LIKE 
  :cleanSearch2 OR to_location__c LIKE :cleanSearch2)
  LIMIT 200];
}
public void clear(){  
lead.clear();  
}  
}
```